# In C, why is 10/3 giving 3.000 when it should give 3.333? (the variables holding 10 and 3 are declared "double")

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, types

I'm trying to solve fractional knapsack, my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct item {
    int index;
    double profit;
    double weight;
    double pw_ratio;
};

void sort(struct item a[], int n) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[i].pw_ratio > a[j].pw_ratio) {
                int temp = a[i].pw_ratio;
                a[i].pw_ratio = a[j].pw_ratio;
                a[j].pw_ratio = temp;
                
                temp = a[i].profit;
                a[i].profit = a[j].profit;
                a[j].profit = temp;
                
                temp = a[i].weight;
                a[i].weight = a[j].weight;
                a[j].weight = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("Sorted items: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", a[i].index, a[i].pw_ratio,
               a[i].profit, a[i].weight);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of items: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int capacity;
    printf("Enter the capacity of knapsack: ");
    scanf("%d", &capacity);
    struct item a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i].index = i + 1;
        printf("Enter profit of item%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%lf", &a[i].profit);
        printf("Enter weight of item%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%lf", &a[i].weight);
        a[i].pw_ratio = (double)a[i].profit / a[i].weight;
        //printf("Profit-weight ratio: %lf", a[i].pw_ratio);
    }
    sort(a, n);
    //solve(a, n);
}
```

When I input profit = 10, weight = 3, the `sort` function's output prints `pw_ratio` as `3.000` (instead of `3.333`), however the next iteration item (i.e second item) gives perfect decimal value.

I tried debugging, and when I print `pw_ratio` in the `main` function itself (where I'm taking input for `profit` and `weight`) it is absolutely correct, i.e 10/3 will give 3.33, 20/9 gives 2.222 and so on. What is the issue here, and how to solve this?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. All that manual input and processing is distracting from the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `int temp = a[i].pw_ratio;` you store the ratio in an `int` variable, effectively truncating it. When you later do `a[j].pw_ratio = temp;` the original value is not restored.

The whole swapping procedure could be simplified by swapping the whole `struct item` at once, which will then use the correct types everywhere.

```c
if (a[i].pw_ratio > a[j].pw_ratio) {
    struct item temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;

    // swap back index
    int idx = a[i].index;
    a[i].index = a[j].index;
    a[j].index = idx;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your sorting function uses `temp`, an `int` variable, to temporarily store values when swapping. This causes some of the values to be truncated to an `int`. You also don't swap `index` although it's not clear if that's a mistake or intentional.

Note, you can use the standard library function `qsort` to sort an array. In addition to being more correct and less code, it will be more efficient when your array gets longer.

Comment: This works. The index is intentional. How do I write comparison function for qsort?

Comment: @Sanskriti Using `qsort` could look [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/83rxPKzG5) - but that would not preserve `index` in the swapping.

Comment: A simple way to handle the `index` member is to reconstruct them after the sort with a simple loop: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { a[i].index = i + 1; }`

Comment: @chqrlie That's a good observation so the question is if `index` should really be in the `struct` at all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: it is indeed a surprising design choice. Making `index` a member of the structure allows any function that receives a pointer to an array element to use this index for its purpose, such as printing it or testing it for other purposes.

Comment: @chqrlie That's true I guess. I'd prefer to send in the `index` separately to such functions though, `func(a, index)` to let them do the lookup.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Another advantage: it allows for stable sorting in `qsort`.

Answer (score 3):

The `sort` function uses an `int` variable to perform the value swap, causing a conversion of the `double` values to `int`, which effectively truncates the values.  You should just swap the structures and reconstruct the `index` members after the sort.

Also note that your sorting method does not work: you should only compare elements with index values `i` and `j` such that `i < j`.

Here is a modified version:

```
void sort(struct item a[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[i].pw_ratio > a[j].pw_ratio) {
                struct item temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i].index = i + 1;
    }
    
    printf("Sorted items: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", a[i].index, a[i].pw_ratio,
               a[i].profit, a[i].weight);
    }
}
```

You could also use `qsort` defined in `<stdlib.h>`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_ratios(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct item *aa = a;
    const struct item *bb = b;
    int cmp = (aa->pw_ratio > bb->pw_ratio) - (aa->pw_ratio < bb->pw_ratio);
    // implement stable sorting:
    //     keep elements that compare equal in the original order.
    if (cmp == 0) {
        cmp = (aa->index > bb->index) - (aa->index < bb->index);
    }
    return cmp;
}

void sort(struct item a[], int n) {
    qsort(a, n, sizeof(*a), compare_ratios);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i].index = i + 1;
    }
    
    printf("Sorted items: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", a[i].index, a[i].pw_ratio,
               a[i].profit, a[i].weight);
    }
}
```